# Why are these 2 versions of code giving different outputs

Tags: c++, math, polynomial-math, polynomials

I have 2 versions of the same polynomial but they are giving siginificantly different outputs and I am not sure why.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

float v1(float alpha)
{
    alpha = 1.0-alpha;
    alpha = 1.0-pow(alpha, 5.0)*6.0 - 15.0*pow(alpha,4.0) +10.0*pow(alpha,3.0);
    return alpha;
}

float v2(float alpha)
{
    alpha = 1.0-alpha;
    alpha = 1.0-alpha*alpha*alpha*(alpha*((alpha*6.0) -15.0) + 10.0);
    return alpha;
}

int main()
{
    for(float t=0; t<=1; t+=0.1)
    {
        float a1 = v1(t);
        float a2 = v2(t);
        std::cout<< a1 << ", " << a2 << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
-10, 0
-5.09444, 0.00856005
-1.99008, 0.05792
-0.17992, 0.16308
0.74944, 0.31744
1.125, 0.5
1.19456, 0.68256
1.13392, 0.83692
1.05408, 0.94208
1.00844, 0.99144
```

Comment: Because floating point arithmetic.

Comment: They do very different things. And it's not only because of floating-point issues, but the functions really do calculate different things.

Comment: Give a look at how IEEE floating points are structured and you will understand

Comment: order of brackets i assume
1.0 - [ alpha pow(alpha, 5.0)*6.0 ]  - [15.0*pow(alpha,4.0) ] + [ 10.0*pow(alpha,3.0)]
i replaced some( for [ to make the steps more clear

Comment: `for(float t=0; t<=1; t+=0.1)` -- Be aware that adding `0.1` to a `float` does not produce exact results.  If the terminating condition of the loop were `t <= 10` or greater, you will probably see the loss of accuracy in the looping (the loop will not execute the number of times you expected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression in `v2` is mathematically equivalent to

```
1.0 - (6*pow(alpha, 5) - 15*pow(alpha, 4) + 10*pow(alpha, 3))
```

Note the extra set of parenthesis.  Your two functions [are not equivalent](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1+-+(6%CE%B1%5E5+-+15%CE%B1%5E4+%2B+10%CE%B1%5E3)+and+1+-+6%CE%B1%5E5+-+15%CE%B1%5E4+%2B+10%CE%B1%5E3+from+%CE%B1%3D0+to+1) for the same reason `1 - x^2 + x` is not equivalent to `1 - (x^2 + x)`

If you add an extra set of parenthesis around to the expression in `v1` you get the [same result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60e78341b010cc08) from both functions (aside from some small floating-point rounding errors).

Comment: oh man, I must have been REALLY tired earlier today, off course those are not equivalent